# Rails can I use form tag inside form for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a form like this, because I just want to use :pass_value to pass value to other properties in controller. But it does not work. Could you please provide a right way to do this?

```
<% form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= text_tag :pass_value %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannnot use form_tag inside another form. But if you want to pass the value of :pass_value actually not as an attribute, try making use of virtual attribute. You can make use of `:attr_accessor` method.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use a form tag inside a form. But you can use one of:

a) `fields_for`

if this is a nested model, you can use it something like:

```
fields_for :widget do |g|
   g.text_field :widget_name
end
```

doc for fields_for: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

b) `text_field_tag`

if it's just an independent field

```
<%= text_field_tag :some_value %>
```

doc for text_field_tag:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag

Comment: Thanks for your help. Second solution can solve my problem, but problem is if I have four text fields, let's say they are name, pass_value, age, address. pass_value just used to pass value, not an attribute of the model. Also, I want pass_value to be in the second place. But if I use text_field_tag, I think the pass value can only be placed before or after the form.

Comment: no, text field tag is always placed inside the form or it doesn't work. You use it just the same as `f.text_field` and can place it anywhere you like - in amongst the other fields if you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use raw html tags, such as

```
input type="hidden" name="person[pass_value]" value=@person.pass_value
```

it's just html form after all